# How to fix creation of table with reserved keywork (key)?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, unit-testing, h2, liquibase

I use liquibase to initilize my h2 database for unit testing, but there is a problem with one table using "key" as name of column.

I tried "_key" as name, it works but the database (which I cannot change its schema) use "key" as a column name, so i have to put @Column("\"key\"") in my domain class. This works for SQL Server (production database) but doesn't for h2 (in memory db for testing)

In Liquibase xml:( for unit test)

```
   <column name='_key' type="varchar(100)">
      <constraints nullable="true" />
   </column>
```

My domain:

```
    @Column(name = "_key", length = 100)
    //@Column(name = "\"key\"", length = 100)
    private String key;
```

So I have to uncomment the first option and comment the second to make the unit test works and do the opposite to make the application work.

Using the

`@Column(name = "\"key\"", length = 100)` 
with
`<column name="key" type="varchar(100)">` or 
`<column name="\"key\"" type="varchar(100)">` or
`<column name='"key"' type="varchar(100)">`

returns an error:

> Schema-validation: missing column [key] in table [displaymessages]

and the query that creates the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.displaymessages (
  id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  "'key'" VARCHAR(100),
  value VARCHAR(1000),
  type INT NOT NULL,
  createdon date NOT NULL,
  modifiedon date,
  isdeleted INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_DISPLAYMESSAGES PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

On the changeset that creates the table/column, you can add an attribute `objectQuotingStrategy` with the value `QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS`, as shown in the example below:

```
<changeSet author="Sir Cuke Umber" id="1::addTable::labelA" labels="AAA" objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS">
    <createTable tableName="LABELA">
        <column name="message" type="TEXT">
            <constraints nullable="true" primaryKey="false" unique="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

This attribute can also be added at the root changelog level if you want every identifier to be quoted.

Comment: thanks for your response, i tested your suggestion but it doesn't work.
the test don't found the table itself.
`Schema-validation: missing table [displaymessages]`

Comment: What is the actual name of the table in the database? The issue with quoting is that many databases have automatic case-change behavior, which can be problematic. Oracle, for example, when creating an object named `test` with no quotes will actually create an object named `TEST` (all upper case). But if you create `"test"` with quotes, the actual object will be named `test` (lower case, as specified in the create statement). If you're working with two platforms that handle that differently and the objects already exist, then adding the quotes can lead to the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Steve, i think quoting will not fix my issue.
So let return to the main quetion, is there a way to let h2 reserved word handling behave as sqlserver handling ? i mean putting double-quotes using sqlserver works but h2 don't work :(

Comment: Nothing built-in, no. You would need to write a plugin/extension to express the custom functionality you want.